# Best Practice - Shift + Enter in Input

Tags: html, forms

Implementing a UI form and I'm curious what the best practice is for handling `SHIFT + ENTER` with a HTML input focused.

In a textarea this seems clear: add a new line / don't submit the form.

In an input, I'm not quite certain: should this just do nothing? Submit the form (as with `ENTER`)?

Comment: Are you trying to ask how should the form behave to optimize user experience?

Comment: Don't do anything with it, leave whatever the default is

Answer (score 0):

For input type, there's too much variation from browser to browser. In Firefox, shift+enter does nothing and acts like pressing enter. In Chrome, shift+enter means open a new window and press enter. I would leave as default and do nothing to it.